# Finding the sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am supposed to find the sum up to $n$ terms of the series $n/(1+n^2+n^4)$ I found out that the series converges to $0.5$ but what if the series doesn't go up to infinity.

Comment: @MaliMish I rolled back your edit. OP appears to be asking for an expression for the nth term of the series as opposed to the asymptote. The question is indeed not 100 % clear, but it's much better to ask the poster for clarification than just editing in your assumptions.

Comment: @DanielR Exactly I was about to do the same

Comment: Series converges to 0.5 not 5. That is what the question in edit was. Series itself is not $n/(1+n^2+n^4)$ but $\sum \dfrac{n}{1+n^2+n^4}$ - this was the only fix, I understood what the OP was asking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$\frac{n}{1+n^2+n^4}=\frac{1/2}{n^2-n+1}-\frac{1/2}{n^2+n+1}=
\frac{1/2}{n^2-n+1}-\frac{1/2}{(n+1)^2-(n+1)+1}.$$

Comment: I already noted that but it didn't took me anywhere

Comment: @bulbasaur Try a telescopic approach.

Comment: Of course..exactly what I have been trying to do

Comment: @bulbasaur Any further doubt?